# Test running as expected from intelliJ IDE but not when running it from the command line TestNG

Tags: java, maven, testng

I am trying to run my tests from the command line using Maven when I run the tetst directly from intelliJ IDE tests run as expected, when I try to run then using `mvn test` I am getting the following messages:

```
-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running TestSuite
Configuring TestNG with: org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.conf.TestNG652Configurator@34c4973
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.commons.beanutils.converters.BooleanConverter).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
2020-06-29 17:32:49 [ERROR]failed to create 'BaseTest-531000' directory
Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.99 sec

Results :

Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
```

And this is my POM.xml:

```
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.takeaway.automation</groupId>
    <artifactId>takeaway-project</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <testng.version>7.1.0</testng.version>
        <awaitility.version>3.0.0</awaitility.version>
    </properties>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>8</source>
                    <target>8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/log4j/log4j -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.testng/testng -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>${testng.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.12</version>
        </dependency>     
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-configuration2 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-configuration2</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-lang/commons-lang -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat/jackson-dataformat-yaml -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.3</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

And my tests are under the class name is HTTPTester.java where there I got all my testng Test cases:

```
 src/testjava/com/takeaway/automation/tests/api/HTTPTester.java
```

Answer (score 2):

Unless you configure it otherwise, the surefire maven plugin is expecting your test to be at:

```
src/test/java/com/takeaway/automation/tests/api/HTTPTest.java
```

(`src/test/java`, not `src/testjava` and `*Test.java` not `*Tester.java`)

See more details here: https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/inclusion-exclusion.html

Comment: So as I understood from you I did put the test class in the right location, it is still not running...

Answer (score 1):

OK, I found what was missing , adding 'maven-surefire-plugin' plugin was missing:

```
 <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
                <configuration>
                    <includes>
                        <include>HTTPTester.java</include>
                    </includes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```